# dense sets and uncountable sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ uncountable meaning $|A| \not \leq \aleph_0$ , prove that there is $B \subset A$ countable $|B| \leq \aleph_0$ such that :

$C = A- B$ is dense meaning $\forall x \in C \forall \epsilon >0 |C \cap (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)|\not \leq \aleph_0$

For instance $A = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ and $B= \{2\}$ so $C = [0,1]$ is dense in every point.

I need a hint on how to construct $B$ given $A$ , or at least how to prove that such $B$ must exist

Thanks

Comment: Let $V$  be the set of all bounded open intervals, with rational endpoints, that have countable intersection with $A$. Let $B=\cup V.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $B$ as you've defined it isn't countable. You want $B\cap A$ (see my answer below).

Comment: @NoahSchweber.... Yes. I meant to write $ B=(\cup V)\cap A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that your definition of "dense" is not the usual one.

The most obvious difference is the cardinality restriction; normally we just demand nonempty intersection. Note that e.g. under your definition, no countable set can be dense.  The second difference is that really you're talking about $C$'s "density" *with respect to itself* rather than all of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}$. I think a better name for your property would be "**uncountably dense-in-itself**."

So we want to show:

> If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there is some countable $B$ such that $C=A-B$ is uncountably dense-in-itself.

*(Note that we could drop the cardinality restriction on $A$: if $A$ is countable, take $B=A$ and note that the emptyset is vacuously uncountably dense-in-itself.)*

The key point is that we want to build $C$ from $A$ by throwing away the "bad points." Your example follows this: $A$ isn't uncountably dense-in-itself yet, because of the isolated point $2$, so we "throw it away" to get $C$. To solve the problem, we need to do two things:

- Figure out precisely what "bad point" means.
- Show that there are only countably many "bad points."

The right notion of "bad point" isn't hard to come up with: we say that $a\in A$ is bad if there is some open interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $I\cap A$ is countable. The interesting part is showing that there are only countably many bad points. For this, I have two hints:

- Show that we can restrict attention, in the definition of "bad point," to intervals $I$ of the form $(p, q)$ with $p, q$ rational. Note that there are only countably many rationals, hence only countably many intervals of this form.
- Call an interval $I$ with rational endpoints **bad** if $I\cap A$ is countable. Then every bad point is contained in a bad interval. Now, how many bad points can a given bad interval contain? And since there are only countably many bad intervals, what does this say about the total number of bad points?

---

There is one slight subtlety in the above approach. We've focused, in the definition of "bad point," on intervals with rational endpoints rather than intervals of the form $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$. This let us count the relevant intervals. It's a good exercise to convince yourself that this was an important thing to do.

---

It's worth noting that a related problem poses an interesting new difficulty. Suppose we drop the uncountability requirement: a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is **dense-in-itself** if for every $a\in A$ and open interval $I\ni a$, we have $I\cap (A\setminus\{a\})\not=\emptyset$. Then the claim is:

> If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there is some countable $B\subseteq A$ such that $C=A-B$ is dense-in-itself.

*(As before we can drop the requirement that $A$ be uncountable.)*

At first glance this seems easier: we just want to throw away the **isolated points** of $A$, and it's easy to show that there are only countably many of these (use the rational interval trick again). However, we run into a problem: there may be non-isolated points of $A$ which *become* isolated after throwing away the isolated points! E.g. take $$A=\{0\}\cup\{{1\over 2},{1\over 3},{1\over 4},...\}.$$ $0$ is not a limit point of $A$, but once we throw away all the non-limit points of $A$ we are left with just $\{0\}$, which is now a limit point.

*(If you like, add "$[17,200]$" to the $A$ defined above to make it uncountable. My point isn't about cardinality, though, it's about the way points can be arranged in a set.)*

We need to keep throwing away isolated points over and over again - in fact, infinitely often. This process is the [Cantor-Bendixson derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)), and to solve this problem you'll wind up going through the Cantor-Bendixson *theorem* that every closed set can be written as the union of a countable set and a perfect *(= closed with no isolated points)* set. (Note that this doesn't immediately solve the problem above, since there is no requirement that $A$ be closed!)

Comment: is taking $B = \{ x \in A | \exists \epsilon>0  : A \cap (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)|\leq \aleph_0$ } works ?, how can i show that $B$ is countable set

Comment: @Ahmad That is indeed the right $B$. As to how you show that it's countable, that's what the two bulletpoints in my answer address.